# Why does every code related to font_awesome_flutter package gives an error including the import package code?

Tags: flutter, package

## SITUATION

I made a project in another device and when I am using the same project in another device. It gives an font_awesome_flutter package error all over the code. And gives an error saying, 
**Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart'.
Try creating the file referenced by the URI, or Try using a URI for a file that does exist.** 
 Same issue occurs in vs code as well as in android studio

*How should I tackle this?*

### TRIED

I also tried running `flutter pub get` but does not work.

**pubspec.yaml file**

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  font_awesome_flutter: ^8.8.1
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3
```

**flutter doctor -v** seems good too.

```
PS G:\Current Work\nikeshoeapp-20200809T055655Z-001\nikeshoeapp> flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.20.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.388], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.20.1 at C:\src\flutter\flutter
    • Framework revision 2ae34518b8 (3 days ago), 2020-08-05 19:53:19 -0700
    • Engine revision c8e3b94853
    • Dart version 2.9.0

 
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.1)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\Aman Chaudhary\AppData\Local
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.1
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 48.0.2
    • Dart plugin version 193.7361
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] VS Code (version 1.47.3)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\Aman Chaudhary\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.13.2

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • sdk gphone x86 arm (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 11 (API 30) (emulator)

• No issues found!
```

Please Let me know what should I try?

Comment: Have you tried running `flutter clean` ?

Comment: ran,
error still exists

Comment: Could you try removing the `import` statement that gives the error and importing it again using the `IDE's` intellisense ?

Comment: I am new to flutter, how to do that in vs code?

Comment: After removing the `import statement`, go the the line that shows an error, place your cursor over it, press the bulb that shows and select `import package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart`

Comment: It does not give an option for importing font awesome flutter package

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219483/discussion-between-derek-and-aman-chaudhary).

Answer (score 0):

Try file -> invalidate/restart and then click on invalidate and restart.
If it doesn't work, try running this

’’’
flutter clean pub cache
’’’

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this problem, in my case i finished my project and done a
`flutter clean` and done `flutter build apk --release`
and the error was

*Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart'. Try creating the file referenced by the URI, or Try using a URI for a file that does exist.*

**Solution**

These commands saved me

1. `flutter clean`
2. `flutter packages get`
3. `flutter pub get`
4. `flutter build apk --release`

*Still i didn't get the difference between* `flutter packages get` and `flutter pub get`